# How to fix ClassCastException when using jaxb dependency

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, osgi, jira-plugin

I am developing jira server plugin which uses a 3rd party library which contains jaxb as a runtime dependency. Following is the pom xml file of that 3rd party library

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
  <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.12</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.20</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And also a jaxb version (v2.3.0) is available in the jira server runtime. I am getting the following error

> ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/JiraServer/Jira%20Software/Atlassian/Jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to
> bundle://252.0:18/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.

I tried to exclude the jaxb from the 3rd party library that I am using, but it did not worked for me. Can someone please advice how to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Mifraz

Comment: I had a problem like yours, I resolved it, changing the jaxb-api scope to provided

Comment: Hi @imperezivan, I cant change the 3rd party library pom xml file(because it is added as a runtime dependency to support java 10 since the jre does not have jaxb anymore). So I cant change the scope. Is there any way that we can handle this issue from my plugin xml.